# Facebook canvas app not saving Sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, omniauth

I made a test facebook app just to play around and I am using sessions to store the authentification. I am using omniauth. When I go to log in from http://fbbtest.heroku.com/ and then refresh the page the session is still saved and it says that I am logged in. When I try it from the canvas http://apps.facebook.com/herokutestapp/ it logs me in, redirects back and says that I am logged in but then when I manually refresh it then says that I am not logged in. Is there something special that I have to do with sessions in rails 3 so that it also works in the facebook canvas?

This what I currently have in my controllers and views

```
  def index

  end

  def create
    session['fb_auth'] = request.env['omniauth.auth']
    session['fb_token'] = session['fb_auth']['credentials']['token']
    session['fb_error'] = nil
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def destroy
    clear_session
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def failure
    clear_session
    session['fb_error'] = 'In order to use this site you must allow us access to your Facebook data<br />'
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def clear_session
    session['fb_auth'] = nil
    session['fb_token'] = nil
    session['fb_error'] = nil
  end
```

Index View

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Heroku FB Test application</h1><br />
    <div class="center"><br />
<%=session[:fb_error]%>     
    <% if session[:fb_token] %>
      <p>
        Successfully logged in.
      </p>
      <a href='logout'>Logout</a>
    <% else %>
        <%= session[:fb_error] %><br />
            <%= link_to "Log in with Facebook", "/auth/facebook",:class => "popup", :"data-width" => 600, :"data-height" => 400 %> <br />
        <p>
            please log in
        </p>
    <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What browser are you using? Does it affect more than one browser?

Comment: Sorry if you cannot test it right now. Heroku is down :(

Comment: Do you have more than 1 dyno running on Heroku?

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Answer (score 9):

The problem you're possibly running into is that Rails CSRF forgery detection is creaming some part of your authentication because the requests are coming in as HTTP Method POST.

The first line in your ApplicationController is probably something like:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  [...]
```

Remove that 'protect_from_forgery' line and see if that helps with your problem.  If that turns out to be the case, go back and set that up on a more limited basis (just the relevant controllers, see documentation here:  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html )

There's an great example for getting Omniauth working at http://www.communityguides.eu/articles/16, and the full sample code is at https://github.com/markusproske/omniauth_pure.  On that, they have the following:

```
class ServicesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:create, :signin, :signup, :newaccount, :failure]
  protect_from_forgery :except => :create
```

You need some variant of both those lines to make omniauth, facebook, and rails sessions play well together.  If that doesn't work out for you, post your OmniAuth::Builder information from environment/production.rb (with details XXXed out) and any other related code in the controller you use for authentication, that will be helpful for debugging this.

It may be easier when developing rails apps using facebook to debug using http://tunnlr.com or another service (or just an ssh tunnel http://blog.kenweiner.com/2007/09/reverse-ssh-tunnel-for-facebook.html)  that lets you run the debugger on your local machine, it is very helpful for figuring these sorts of problems out.

Comment: Is there any downside to turn off the protect_from_forgery for the create action?

Comment: oldergod: nope. rails' protect_from_forgery only does stuff when it's coming from a form inside the rails application.  This says nothing about the safety of any particular action, just that the rails anti-forgery methods aren't helpful.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Sessions and cookies in Facebook iframes are very difficult to use, but not impossible. I've faced this a few times when trying to develop vote-once-per-day contests.

The solution is to use P3P headers. Honestly I'm not too sure how they work, but it reduces issues of cross-browser cookies in iframes - especially IE and Safari.

Add the following to the top of each page:

```
header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
```

This may not solve your issue exactly but hopefully it can help get you on the right path.

Comment: This solution is only really necessary for Internet Explorer.  The issue above seems to be occurring in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: A P3P header is not the solution. That only applies to third-party cookies in Internet Explorer in the default security configuration. If it is a third-party cookie problem a much different approach is called for, and a P3P header just confuses the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If I `cookies.permanent.signed[:fb_auth]` it allows me to return to the application in facebook without needing to re-log in. Is this the best way to get around sessions not working through iFrames?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a third-party cookie issue. Are you certain that using cookies.permanent.signed works properly if you have only accessed the site through Facebook? Try clearing the cookies, restarting the browser, and then going to the Facebook canvas page and testing again.

In Firefox, try going to Tools->Options->Privacy and seeing if "Accept third-party cookies" is unchecked. If it is, try checking it and testing again.

It's not at all surprising that third-party cookies may be causing you problems, the confusing part is why using a persistent cookie should make any difference.

If you do verify that third-party cookies are the problem, I'm afraid there is no easy solution if you want the app to be accessible by everyone. You have to stop using cookies altogether, and maintain session state using only values passed by GET/POST.

Comment: And by "maintain session state using only values passed by GET/POST" you mean passing your own generated session key to/with all the requests that the canvas app sends/responds to?